# Is it possible to put a javascript function in a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Non-programmer here, trying to figure something out.

I have a javascript function in the header of my document that upon page load it opens another page in an iframe and reveals an svg file on my server for minor online editing.  I would like to place my javascript function in a php file, so that these folder locations of the svg files cannot be determined for anyone to download these svg files freely.

Currently I have this on my html header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function loaded()
            {
            document.getElementById("myiframe").src="http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/mypage.html?url=myotherfolder/"+window.location.search.substr(1);
            }
            onload=loaded;
        </script>
```

Since I have heard that php is a server side script and not viewable, I thought this would mask the location of these files on my server.

I want to remove this javascript code from my header and place it in a php file and replace the header code with either of these:

```
<script src="phpjavafile.php"></script>
```

or

```
    <?php include ('phpjavafile.php'; ?>
```

and finally put the javascript into a php file like this:

```
<?php
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function loaded()
                {
                document.getElementById("myiframe").src="http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/mypage.html?url=myotherfolder/"+window.location.search.substr(1);
                }
                onload=loaded;
            </script>
?>
```

I have tried both of these methods and neither load properly.

I must be doing something wrong.  Am I on the right track, or is there a better way of getting this to work.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Think of the script as nothing more than html (because that's ***exactly*** what it is). How do you output html with php? or plain text?

Comment: nothing more than text, not html

Comment: html is nothing more than text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the echo() function

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo '<script>
some javascript
</script';
?>
```

However if you are just trying to load the php on page load without any php args then just write it out of the  tags.

If you have the JavaScript is another file then using

**PHP**

```
<?php
include 'path/to/javascript/file.php';
?>
```

Should work.

You cannot hide javascript as it is interpreted browser side and not server side so the users browser has to have accesses to the code.

Here is the code I think you are asking for:

**PHP HTML**

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents("path/to/data.html");
?>
<div>
    <?php echo $html; ?>
</div>
```

doesn't use an iframe but should still work. However any relative links will not work unless both files are in the same dir and there will be no iframe functionality without additional css

Comment: If the javascript is not possible to hide, essentially the server path of my files, is it possible to rewrite my javacript function into a pure php script instead?

Comment: Not really. it is editing the scr of a iframe so that will be viewable regardless of how you do it. all HTML and javascript needs to be seen by the browser. you could write a php function to import the data of the file and output it. that would hide the file paths

Comment: That sounds like the solution I need, I guess I will try to explore that option, not sure where to start though.

Comment: i added a bit telling you how to import data and put it into a div

Comment: Awesome!  I will give that a try and share the results!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just output it as text in your PHP file.

```
<?php 
  // Some PHP stuff here
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function loaded(){
    ....
  }
  onload=loaded;
</script>

<?php 
  // Some more PHP stuff here
?>
```

Alternatively, you can just link to it in the usual way from within the same file:

```
<script src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your first example of the php file, will the javascrpt still be visible, like it would in your second alternative js example?

Comment: @Mahogan what do you mean will it still be visible... It has to be visible for it to reach the browser.

Comment: @Mahogan, yes it will. Anything between the <?php ?> tags will be parsed and the resultant HTML will be sent to the browser. Anything in the same file which is not between these tags will be sent to the browser as is.